# pynput install using pip

Tags: apt, python, python3

I get the following error while trying to install pynput using pip:

```
Invalid requirement: 'python-xlib>=0.17; linux in "sys_platform"'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 78, in __init__
    req = Requirement(req)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/packaging-16.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl/packaging/requirements.py", line 94, in __init__
    requirement_string[e.loc:e.loc + 8]))
InvalidRequirement: Invalid requirement, parse error at "'; linux '"
```

How can I get rid of this error?

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me, you can try this..(Works for python 2.7)

```
$ sudo -H python -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
$ sudo -H pip install xlib
$ sudo -H pip install xlib>=0.17
$ sudo -H pip install pynput
```

Comment: I get an error on your first command.

Comment: Could you specify what error you have.  Skip the first & try the rest and let know if it is working  for you.

Comment: As you said, I tried the rest, and got the following error:                                   Invalid requirement: 'python-xlib>=0.17; linux in "sys_platform"'

Comment: Try running just


**sudo -H pip install xlib**

And if the response is :

'Requirement already satisfied: xlib in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.10.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from xlib)'

You should be able to install pynput

Comment: Does not work. I get the same error.

Comment: could you help me with posting the output for the following.

**sudo -H pip install xlib -v**

Comment: Error for sudo -H pip install xlib -v:

Comment: This did work for me.